When I turn the ceiling fan and light I can off light with chain switch
we moved to a new house. In the master room, we have a ceiling fan with light. When we turn on the key, both start to work. With the switch chain, we can turn off the light. we want to reverse it: with a chain switch turn off the fan.

Make and model of the fan is needed, but generally chain switches are wired by design into the fan and cannot be switched over to fan control without changing the internal wiring.  There are add on remotes that can be fitted to most fans. if that would satisfy your situation.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Are you sure there isn't a missing chain?  Often fan lights have a chain to control each.

Most fan/lights the fan is running in the daytime as well as at night, so a separate way to turn off the light is wanted/needed.
